# Why does increasing lambda for a poisson distribution decrease the p-value obtained from a chi-square test?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test

I generated some random numbers that is suppose to follow the Poisson distribution, where n =200 and lambda =20.

```
data <- rpois(200,20)
param <- fitdistr(data, "poisson") 
data.freq <-data.frame(table(data))
freq.os<-vector()
for(i in 1: length(data.freq$data)) freq.os[i]<-(data.freq$Freq[i])
freq.ex <- dpois(as.numeric(as.vector(data.freq$data)), lambda=param$estimate)
chisq.test(freq.os, p=freq.ex, rescale.p=TRUE)
```

Output:

```
    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  freq.os
X-squared = 26.348, df = 24, p-value = 0.3357
```

When I increase lambda to 80, p-value drops:

```
    Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  freq.os
X-squared = 69.687, df = 42, p-value = 0.004616
```

Does this have anything to do with the degree of freedom? I'm confused as to why this is the case.

Comment: Notice that your value for chi-square has increased too. Have you looked at the expected _frequencies_ closely? Are many of them very small?

Comment: I suspect just "dumb luck". When I load the MASS package which I suspect was the source of `fitdistr` and run this only twice with the "lambda" in the rpois call at 20 and 80 I do not see the decrease you see. This should be a caution to you in placing too much value on a p-value. Run the comparison 100 times and report back to the class.